# Rails parent-child association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I am creating a db schema that will represent a library of articles. Each article, however, can have many translations. So, There is a base article, which contains the shared info, and translations for that article. I currently have an article table/class and a translation table/class. Every article has_many translations and so on. My question though, is if there is a good way to delegate methods and find articles with this system.

Should I make my own factory methods on the article class to retrieve the correct translation child? Should I add delegators on the translation so that I can reach back into the parent and get shared info about the article?

Another big concern is where named_scopes would go. Should they go on the article or its translation? I am trying to think of the best way to abstract away the difference between an article and its translation and just have a bunch of articles. Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm more interested on help as to where the logic of getting articles should go. When I want to get an article should I really search for a translation and then just get info from its parent article when I need it or should I be doing everything through the parent?

Comment: It should go to the articles model, as a scope or as a method, as i'm showing you in my answer. And yes, you should get the translation through the article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that i would use a scope to get an article and translation based on a language. It would be like that in the article model :

```
  scope :translation, lambda { |language|
    includes(:translation).
    where("translations.language = ?", language )
  }
```

Comment: But this gets me all articles for a certain language, right? I was wondering if there are any good ways of getting a specific article. Should I just write my own finders?

Comment: you can add a further check even if you have a scope. Thus, you could do Article.translations.first or just do any find you want on the relation.

Comment: You can even take it further by adding another scope that gets you articles that fulfil other conditions, like if they are read. And then do Article.translations.read.